# Collision Detection in Lightning Service Console

Tags: lightning, service-cloud-console

Please tell me how to overcome this error.

When I try to edit a case record in LEX service console. I'm getting the below error.

Im a admin user.

[image]

Comment: Did you actually try to reload the record and edit it again?

Comment: Yeah, I did the same yet I'm getting the same error message. Ideally, the record is not being edited or begun editing by other users.  The case record is private in my Org settings.